# OpenVZ Container cannot access internet

Tags: virtualization, openvz

I have Daedicated Server, and I want to split it on two virtual servers with two diffrent IP Adresses. I bought two exetrnal IP adresses for this server and now I have three, one Main Address, one for firts VPS and one for second VPS.

I have installed Debian 7 x64 on server and OpenVZ, set booting to OpenVZ kernel and created a container with Debian 8.0 and added only external external IP (Main Address is  8x.xxx.132.7x, I have added 8x.xxx.249.20x to container). I ran container and connected to SSH with 8x.xxx.249.20x. This works perfect.

But, when I try to execute `ping google.rs` in container, I get error: `ping: unknown host google.rs`

How to allow internet connection from container?

P.S. I'm trying to fix it from tonight (3 hours). Nothing from internet doesn't help.

Output from container when execute `ifconfig`:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:179 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:158 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:19000 (18.5 KiB)  TX bytes:17609 (17.1 KiB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:89.163.249.207  P-t-P:89.163.249.207  Bcast:89.163.249.207  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Route Table:

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
89.163.132.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
89.163.249.221  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
89.163.249.207  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
89.163.132.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         89.163.132.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Show your route table.

Comment: How to do this? I'm beginier.

Comment: Yeah...you could google (for example) and search for "Linux show route table"...sounds good, right?

Comment: I have updated question with requested information.

Comment: Could you run `ping 8.8.8.8` and show the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: I can `ping 8.8.8.8` from Dedicated Server and from All VPS servers, `reslov.conf` file from VPS contains `nameserver 89.163.132.74` this is a Main IP of Dedicated Server.

Comment: I repleaced `reslov.conf` from Dedicated server to VPS and Internet now works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Great Miljan - glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem, according to the comments:

- DNS name resolution wasn't working correctly.

Solution:

- Replaced `/etc/resolv.conf` with the one from the machine hosting the container.

Answer (score 0):

Had a very frequently occuring problem when using OpenVZ Where the DNS servers would randomly disappear. Have you ensured that all the DNS servers are set correctly and functioning?

Comment: How I can check it? DNS servers on Dedicated or on VPS?